# Disable generating .symver pseudo-op with -fstack-protector-strong?

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-errors, stack, code-generation

I'm trying to build a hardened gcc (4.9.3) for Darwin.

When I build with `-fstack-protector-strong`, the build fails when trying to build libgomp, as it generates assembly with the `.symver` pseudo-op which Apple's ancient GAS doesn't know about.

Is there any flag to disable or work around this particular bit of codegen?

Or do I have to abandon `-fstack-protector-strong`?

(And, I'm curious, is it normal for the compiler's stack protector functionality to generate versioned symbols?)